# How to calculate Friendfetch spell force vs grappled DC?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-2e, forced-movement, difficulty-class

The rules for Pathfinder 2 say something like "if forced movement would break the grappled condition it has to pass the DC (either athletics for grabber or thievery for rope)".

The [Friendfetch](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=860) spell creates forced movement, but how can I know if it beats the DC?

Comment: I know for example. if I SHOVE my friend back from the grappler is my athletics check vs the grabber athletics DC,
but using the spell would it be my Class DC or something like that?

Answer (score 3):

## 1d20 + your spellcasting ability modifier + proficiency bonus

[Immobilized](https://2e.aonprd.com/Conditions.aspx?ID=24) says:

> You can't use any action with the move trait. If you're immobilized by something holding you in place and an external force would move you out of your space, **the force must succeed at a check** against either the DC of the effect holding you in place or the relevant defense (usually Fortitude DC) of the monster holding you in place.

Nothing here strictly demands one check over another, but given the wording that 'the force must succeed at a check', it's clear that the check should be related to the force somehow.

[Step 1](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=315) of the rules for checks states that:

> Start by rolling your d20. You’ll then identify all the relevant modifiers, bonuses, and penalties that apply to the roll. [...]
>
> Nearly all checks allow you to add an ability modifier to the roll. An ability modifier represents your raw capabilities and is derived from an ability score, as described on page 20. [...]
>
> When attempting a check that involves something you have some training in, you will also add your proficiency bonus. [...]

In this case, the force is a spell, and a proper spellcaster has an ability and proficiency associated with their spellcasting, which are the same modifiers used to calculate their spell attack and spell DC. The GM should just call for a check that uses those modifiers: 1d20 + **spellcasting ability modifier + proficiency bonus**.

If caster doesn't have these modifiers, then they must have an ability (or perhaps an item) that allows them to cast a spell despite not being a proper spellcaster. That ability might explain what to use in place of the spell attack and spell DC, and if so you can just use that for this force vs immobized check too. For example, if friendfetch were an [innate spell](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=279) then:

> **You're always trained in spell attack rolls and spell DCs** for your innate spells, even if you aren't otherwise trained in spell attack rolls or spell DCs. If your proficiency in spell attack rolls or spell DCs is expert or better, apply that proficiency to your innate spells, too. **You use your Charisma modifier as your spellcasting ability modifier** for innate spells unless otherwise specified.

Finally, this force vs immobized check isn't a counteract check, because counteracting has different rules to determine what happens on crits, successes, and failures. Whereas the immobilized condition already tells us that the forced movement works on a success.

Comment: +1 - this is the correct way of things, and there's no indication we should be using the counteract rules here.

Answer (score 1):

When one effect would end another and no more specific rule applies, you should roll a Counteract check. In the case of Friendfetch, it will be a spell Counteract roll, which is described in the Counteract rules as:

> For spells, the counteract check modifier is your spellcasting ability modifier plus your spellcasting proficiency bonus, plus any bonuses and penalties that specifically apply to counteract checks.

So you would roll a d20 plus your Spell Attack Modifier plus any bonuses or penalties to Counteract checks.